# Why does WiFi speed vary on devices on the same network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

I have 50mbps speed internet connection from some provider.  WiFi is enabled and my mobile and laptops are connected to it.

My mobile shows speed as 40+ Mbps, but the laptop only shows 3 Mbps and it's dead slow.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?  Anything to do with Windows updates?

Comment: Can you provide more specifics on: the router, the laptop and the mobile?

Comment: laptop: windows 10, mobile:  Android,

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific in my request: What wifi bands does your router, laptop and android support? If you don't know the answer to that please rewrite ([edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1578693/edit)) your question to include the name and type of your devices.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a windows update issue (if the drivers installed aren't optimal), but I'd say it's more likely that this has to do something with your power options in Windows.

Find advanced power options, and check if any *USB* or *Wireless* settings are set to "power saver" when your laptop is on battery.

Comment: my battery is dead and the laptop is working only when connected to power. as soon as I switch off the power, laptop shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting Steps to follow:

On the laptop, uninstall the Wireless driver, restart the computer and then install the same or preferably newer Wireless driver. Restart again.

Doing this updates the TCP/IP settings related to the driver.  See if the speed returns to normal after the above.

Also try the laptop on a different wireless connection (friend, coffee shop) and see if this improves the speed.

Consider an external USB Wireless adapter if the above changes do not work.